# REST API : Using @QueryParam to load data from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, jersey, jax-rs

for my restful service with Jersey, I did not find how to load data from MongoDB, using @QueryParam, otherwise I want to have the possibility to search a user by passing his id in the url : 
**localhost:9999/home/users/user?id=547ec** this should load the specific data for the user which id=547ec.

Here is my code, it returns a blank page :

```
@Path("/user")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String getUserByID(@QueryParam("_id") String id) {

    String returnString = "";
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id",id);
    DB db = null;

    try{

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        db = mongo.getDB("mfj");
        DBCollection dbc = db.getCollection("user");
        DBCursor cursorByID = dbc.find(query);
        JSON json =new JSON();
        returnString =json.serialize(cursorByID);

    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `_id != id`. In the URL, you are using `id` but the `@QueryParam` expects `id`.
2. `new BasicDBObject("_id",id);` is a problem. When you query with the id, you should query with `ObjectId`. So

   ```
   `new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(id));
   ```
3. You just get the first `DBObject` from the `DBCursor`. You can just call it's `toString()` to get the JSON. So

   ```
   DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
   DBObject object = cursor.next();
   returnString = object.toString();
   ```
4. Not an issue, just a matter of design preference, but I would use a `@PathParam` instead and just put the id in the path instead of a query parameter. So

   ```
   @Path("/{id}")
   public Sting yourMethod(@PathParam("id") String id)

   // then use .../hello/users/3298ru2390r8
   ```

Put altogether might look something like

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

@Path("/users")
public class MongoResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMongoObject(@PathParam("id") String id) throws Exception {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mfj");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("user");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(id));
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
        DBObject object = cursor.next();
        if (object == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return Response.ok(object.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

The following should work (tested myself), given `547ec` is the actual id

> `localhost:9999/home/users/547ec`

As an aside, the `MongoClient` is thread safe so it recommended to just create one instance, instead of one for each request like you are currently doing.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, for your example just remove /home from localhost:9999/home/users/547ec.

Comment: Depends on the application path. I just assumed it was home. But if it's just `/`, yes then you are correct. :-)